# Switch front and rear tire for distributing wear

Tags: tire, road-bike, wear

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I change both tires when I need to change one?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/should-i-change-both-tires-when-i-need-to-change-one)

On my road bike, my rear tire has much more wear as my front tire (reported by others on this site as well).

Should I switch my front and rear tire to distribute this wear evenly, or let the rear tire wear more and replace only the rear?

Comment: I agree, this is pretty much an exact dupe of the earlier question. @GvS, closing this, as there's nothing to differentiate the two. (If there's something not addressed in the earlier question, please edit this to indicate as such and we can re-open this.)

Comment: The questions are different, but the answers from the other question answers mine as well. I know what (not) to do now.

Comment: Good to hear. Are there aspects of this that would be particularly different on a road bike? (That's the only difference I can see.) If so, please edit this to emphasize those differences and I'd be happy to re-open, if it might get more detailed answers for road tires.

Comment: @neil fyi the system removes any comments containing the dupe url once it is edited into the body of the post at the time of closure. Otherwise we'd have a ton of duplicate links in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have flat-spots on the rear tyre and I am not sure whether I would want that on the front. Plus you will be spending a lot longer with the tyre levers if you 'rotate' them. Valves are a bit sensitive too - mess with the tyre/tube too often and the valves can 'waggle' out of the tube. Personally I would let the back one wear out and replace it when it is 'done'.

But this all changes if you are on a long-distance tour. If you were going from Sierra Leone to Somalia, dodging lions and land-mines, then you probably would not find too many places on the way to stock up on fresh Schwalbe Marathon Plus tyres. Therefore, on the long tour, you would do well to 'rotate' the tyres (giving them a good inspect) on a regular basis.